# An error occurred during local report processing.;An unexpected error occurred in Report Processing. Index was outside the bounds of the array. Rdlc

Tags: c#, backend

I have one method for generate file stream, I called the method two time line by line, I am facing outside the bounds of the array, when i call it one time it works fine

```
public byte[] GenerateReportAsync(string reportName, string reportType, Dictionary<string, string> parameters)
{
    string path = Path.Combine(Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location), "Common", "Reports", reportName);
    Encoding.RegisterProvider(CodePagesEncodingProvider.Instance);
    Encoding.GetEncoding("utf-8");
    
    try
    {
        //ReportViewer report = new ReportViewer();
        //report.LocalReport.ReportEmbeddedResource = path;
        LocalReport report = new LocalReport(path);
        Dictionary<string, string> parameters2 = new Dictionary<string, string>(parameters);
        var result = report.Execute(GetRenderType(reportType), 1, parameters2);
        return result.MainStream;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        var exception = ex.ToString();
    }
    return null;
}
```

This is my method when i call it two time it shows error i mentioned

```
var getCertificateFileStream = GenerateReportAsync("CertificateWithBorder.rdlc", "pdf", parametersCertificate);
var getFileStream =  GenerateReportAsync("ReportWithBorder.rdlc", "pdf", reportParameter);
```

Comment: Can you include the full exception as text in your question? When it pops up in the debugger, you can select "Copy details".

Comment: _"when i call it one time it works fine"_ - Are you mutating something like a shared list of shared dictionary that isn't thread safe?

Comment: what libaries/packages are you using here?

Comment: Ok wait your Method says it wants to return a byte array, uet you return result.MainStream, which isnt a byte array, but  a object of the type ReportStream. Did you really give us your actual code?

Answer (score 0):

Ok so from what I have been able to find, the issue has been noticed and discussed before in https://github.com/amh1979/AspNetCore.Reporting/issues/16 .

Using that thread and some research I can only tell you this: this package is not being maintained anymore. So you should switch to a different library.